# A sequence of nested unbounded closed intervals $L_1\supseteq L_2\supseteq L_3\supseteq\cdots$ with $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}L_n = \varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the following argument correct?

> Prove that there exists a  sequence of nested unbounded closed intervals $L_1\supseteq
>  L_2\supseteq L_3\supseteq\cdots$ with $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}L_n =
>  \varnothing$. (An unbounded closed interval has the form $[a,\infty) = \{x\in\mathbf{R}:x\ge a\}$).

*Solution*. Consider the nested intervals $L_1 = [1,\infty),L_2 = [2,\infty),L_3 = [3,\infty)\cdots$, Now assume that we have an $x\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}L_n$ and let $k\in\mathbf{N}$, from hypothesis $x\in L_{k} = [k,\infty)$ then $x\ge k$ but $x\neq k$ as that would imply that $x\not\in L_{k+1}$, therefore it must be that $x>k$, then since $k$ was arbitrary it follows that $x$ is an upper bound for $\mathbf{N}$, but this is impossible since we know that the real numbers possess the archimedian property, consequently $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}L_n = \varnothing$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Did you mean: "*There exists* a sequence of nested unbounded closed intervals..."?

Comment: @Sambo Yes i did, my apologies for the sloppiness

Comment: Then yes, your argument is correct. Though I'm not sure why you needed to prove $x>k$; it seems to me that $x \geq k$ would be sufficient.

Comment: Correct although a bit wordy. You could say that if $x$ belongs to every $L_k$ than $x\geq k$ for every $k\in \Bbb N$, which is absurd..... My edit was to change $J$ to $L$ throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is perfectly OK, but if you delete "but $x≠k$ as that would imply that $x∉J_{k+1}$, therefore it must be that $x>k$," from your proof then it reads more fluently.

All you need is an upper bound for $\mathbf{N}$, which is found by $x\ge k$